# Screen resolution when VNCing into a Pi Zero W

Tags: remote, vnc, screen

I am using TightVNC to get into a Raspberry Pi Zero W, running Raspbian.

The pi normally runs headless and I will never attach a monitor to it, only remote in.

When I remote in, I see a small desktop (I would guess 640 x 480), surrounded by black.

How do I see it full screen when VNCing in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -geometry switch on the TightVNC command line will set the geometry as you like it. Where that command actually is depends on how you're starting VNC. Common situations are vncserver, xinetd, or using systemd. I did a write-up on setting up TigerVNC with systemd but can be easily applied to tightvnc. See https://github.com/gitbls/RPiVNCHowTo

Comment: Well, it looks like the `-gemotry` option applies ot the server, not the client. So, while TightVnc is my client,  my server is

Comment: Correct. The geometry is on the server side. Read the note that I linked to and it should be quite obvious, even if you don’t implement that method for your vnc server

Comment: What actually worked for me was Settings/Raspberry Pi Options/System/Set resolution. Thanks for your help. Your guide is excellent

Comment: Yes that will do it if you’re using the built-in feature on Raspbian Full. Great you got it resolved!

Comment: I will, however, award you the answer, for your great GitHub How-To. Thanks